# Managing Entities over multiple database contexts

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am new to EF Core and we are trying to figure out the best way to organize our entities and DBContext across different applications.  An example would be if we were a car dealership, we would have a "sales" account DBContext and a "repair" DBContext.  We have an app for "sales" and an app for "repair.  However, there is one need where the "sales" guy needs to look at at a car that was traded in to see what repairs were done here.  In that case he needs to join sales with repairs.
My question is how can you join entities across DBContext?  If this is not possible, then what is the best way of managing scenarios like this so that you don't put all your entities in the same DBContext for all your apps?

Comment: could you post what you got so far?

Comment: Its a "design" question so I haven't coded anything yet.

Comment: Hi Ken. What concerns do you have with putting your "Sales" and "Repairs" entities in the same DbContext? If you chose to put them in the same DbContext you could have one "Car Dealership" HTTP service that any app that needs to interact with "Sales" and "Repairs" could interact with. This is very scalable. That's the sort of thing we do at my organization- wrapping services around databases.